# Netcdf and fortran structures

Tags: fortran, structure, netcdf

I have this fortran structure.

```
 type custom 
    real :: a,b
    real,dimension(20) ::c,d
    real,dimension(20,50) :: e
 end type custom
```

Then I have another structure like this

```
type custom2
  type(custom):: data
end type custom2
```

now i make an object type(custom2)::pntr

is it possible to write all the data in the structure custom in to netcdf format directly with all the names of the components (i.e. a,b,c,d,e) to be the same. Of course this is using pntr(object). Any solution of this in HDF5 is also welcome. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, yes, this is possible with NetCDF4; you're looking for the [User Defined Data Types](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/netcdf-f90/User-Defined-Data-Types.html) section of the manual.

However, the support for it is poor enough that it may cause problems (and you may end up having to use the f77 interface even in F90).  Here's my really hacky first attempt, which I can't get to compile because the F90 bindings don't allow the nf90_put_var call.  Note too that the magic is all in calculating the offsets, which is non-trivial in Fortran (but is doaable using MPI_Get_Address if you're also using MPI...).  loc() is a common but non-standard function which would allow you to do this, and you could also use iso_c_bindings and c_loc() if you trust the pointer math.

```
PROGRAM netcdf_userdeftypes
    USE netcdf
    implicit none

    type custom
       real :: a,b
       real,dimension(20) ::c,d
       real,dimension(20,50) :: e
    end type custom

    integer :: stat
    integer :: i
    integer, parameter :: ncvars=5
    type(custom) :: cvars(ncvars)
    integer :: ctype_id, cvar_id, file_id, dim_id
    integer :: aoff, boff, coff, doff, eoff

    stat = nf90_create(path="test.nc4", cmode=ior(NF90_CLOBBER,NF90_NETCDF4), ncid=file_id)
    stat = nf90_def_dim(file_id, 'Num Custom Vars', ncvars, dim_id)

    stat = nf90_def_compound(ctype_id, (2+2*20+1*(20*50))*4, 'custom type', ctype_id)

    call calcoffsets(aoff, boff, coff, doff, eoff)
    stat = nf90_insert_compound(file_id, ctype_id, 'a', aoff, NF90_REAL)
    stat = nf90_insert_compound(file_id, ctype_id, 'b', boff, NF90_REAL)
    stat = nf90_insert_array_compound(file_id, ctype_id, 'c', coff, NF90_REAL, 1, 20)
    stat = nf90_insert_array_compound(file_id, ctype_id, 'd', doff, NF90_REAL, 1, 20)
    stat = nf90_insert_array_compound(file_id, ctype_id, 'e', eoff, NF90_REAL, 2, 20*50)

    stat = nf90_def_var(file_id, 'custom variable', ctype_id, [dim_id], cvar_id)
    stat = nf90_enddef(file_id)

    do i=1,ncvars
        cvars(i)%a = ncvars*10+1
        cvars(i)%b = ncvars*10+2
        cvars(i)%c = ncvars*10+3
        cvars(i)%d = ncvars*10+4
        cvars(i)%e = ncvars*10+5
    enddo

    stat = nf90_put_var(file_id, cvar_id, cvars)

    stat = nf90_close(file_id)

CONTAINS
    ! there has to be a better way to do this
    ! loc() is common, and c_loc() could in principle
    ! be used...
    SUBROUTINE calcoffsets(aoff, boff, coff, doff, eoff)
        implicit none
        integer, intent(out) :: aoff, boff, coff, doff, eoff

        type(custom) :: test
        integer :: i,testlen
        type(custom), pointer :: tp
        real, allocatable, dimension(:) :: copy

        test % a = 1.
        test % b = 2.
        test % c = 0.
        test % c(1) = 3.
        test % d = 0.
        test % d(1) = 4.
        test % e = 0.
        test % e(1,1) = 5.

        testlen = inquire( iolength=test )
        allocate( copy( testlen ) )
        copy = transfer( test, copy )

        do i=1,testlen
            if (copy(i) == 1.) aoff = i-1
            if (copy(i) == 2.) boff = i-1
            if (copy(i) == 3.) coff = i-1
            if (copy(i) == 4.) doff = i-1
            if (copy(i) == 5.) eoff = i-1
        enddo

    END SUBROUTINE calcoffsets

END PROGRAM netcdf_userdeftypes
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I have a few doubts about this code. For instance I have to tried to compile the above code. I noticed a few errors as u said. the first error was abt  nf90_put_var as you mentioned. I did not understand what you meant by fortran bindings.  Since cvars is a structure and not an array,  is it possible to write multiple statements like stat = nf90_put_var(file_id, cvar_id, cvars%a) and so on.

Comment: Second I got an error with inquire intrinsic command like this.   testlen = inquire( iolength = test )
                                      1
Error: Keyword argument requires explicit interface for procedure 'inquire' at (1)
I never used this and googled the command but was not very successful in understanding the error

Comment: Third, Can you please explain the offset function or at least these lines 

    testlen = inquire( iolength = test )
    allocate( copy( testlen ) )
    copy = transfer( test, copy )
And yes i do use MPI. So how do I then implement this MPI_Address here. I need to understand this concept completely to proceed. Thanks for ur help

Comment: Re: inquire: you'll need a sufficiently modern compiler (eg, gcc 4.6.x) to use inquire the way I have; you could also use bit_size(), I suppose.

Comment: As to the offset; you have to figure out where each field starts within the data structure.  In this simple case - everything of the same 4-byte type - it is *probable* that everything is in order, and that there is no padding within the structure; but the compiler has freedom to move things around for performance. (On the other hand, you could use a SEQUENCE qualifier to make sure thigns are laid out as you'd expect, but there can be a significant performance hit).  Here, I just label the fields, copy them to an appropriately-sized array of reals, and look them up.

Comment: If you're using MPI anyway, you can use MPI_Get_address() to find the starting addresses of the fields within the structure, and just use those the way you would if you were doing mpi_type_create_struct.